# Активация случайной анимации

Tags: java, android, android-animation

Всем привет!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно как-то лучше сделать рандомный выбор анимации, чем у меня в примере? Так то оно работает, но может есть более лучшее решение?

```
public void BT1(View view) {
        final Animation a0 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_translate);
        final Animation a1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_left);
        final Animation a2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.visibleright);

        final int rand = (int) ( Math.random() * 3 );
        switch (rand){
            case 0:
                bt1.startAnimation(a0);
                break;
            case 1:
                bt1.startAnimation(a1);
                break;
            case 2:
                bt1.startAnimation(a2);
                break;
        }
        fromButton = (String) bt1.getText();
        Validate();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш способ хорош, я могу предложить такой способ - складываем все анимации в массив, и рандомно берем любой элемент массива. Будет что-то типа такого:

```
ArrayList<Animation> animArray = new ArrayList<Animation>();
animArray.add(a0);
animArray.add(a1);
animArray.add(a2);
```

и дальше получаем элемент:

```
Random random = new Random();

for(int i=0; i < animArray.size(); i++){
 animArray.get(random.nextInt(animArray.size()) )
}
```

Либо второй вариант:

```
int randomIndex = (int) (Math.random() * animArray.size());
animArray.get(randomIndex);
```

Третий вариант:

```
int randomIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(animArray.size());
animArray.get(randomIndex);
```

Четвертый вариант:

```
Collections.shuffle(animArray);
for(Animation anim: animArray)
    Log.i(MY_TAG, anim);
```

Все случаи выше не требуют вводить кол-во в рандоме. Для этого мы будем получать размер массива. Вот [примеры](https://www.javacodeexamples.com/java-arraylist-get-random-elements-example/971) получения рандомного индекса из массива.